# better way to handle multiple emits in vue

Tags: vue.js, quasar

I have emits to do if I enter a page to do some magic with a menu, I have a solution but its seems very static and too much code for such fancy modern things like vue or quasar.

On every component I need to emit a event I use this for example:

```
this.$root.$emit('category-one--name')
```

And to receive the emit event and handle stuff I use this:

```
this.$root.$on('category-one--name', this.setSelectBox1)
this.$root.$on('category-otherone--name', this.setSelect2)
this.$root.$on('category-more--name', this.setSelectBox3)
this.$root.$on('category-somemore--name', this.setSelect4)
this.$root.$on('category-ansoson--name', this.setSelectBox5)
```

then I handle stuff with the following:

```
setSelectBox1() {
  this.model = this.categories[1]
},
setSelectBox2() {
  this.model = this.categories[2]
},
```

Is there a better way, for example give the emitted event an Id or something and then to iterate over all in one method and not just to repeat the code?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Emit function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) accept a value as second param so try this:

```
this.$root.$emit('category-change', this.name);
```

Then:

```
this.$root.$on('category-change', this.setSelectBox);


setSelectBox(category) {
  // set model here
},
```

Comment: @CamelCase like in this answer. you should pass the parameter (maybe string or object) and make subsequent decisions based on it.